# How can i make the color take 100% of the width

Tags: html, css

[I want the blue color to take up the whole bar from start to end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngvB4.png)

I want the color to take up all the space in the div line

Im using the visual studio layout page so it created itself

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link href="~/css/Logo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" >
            <div style=" background-color:cornflowerblue" class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex  justify-content-around" >
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1" >
                        <li>
                            <img class="logoimg" src="~/Images/SpaceRocket.png" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link  font-weight-bold text-dark " asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: Probably you need to set `style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"` to header, nav or body tag. But your code is working as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link href="~/css/Logo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" >
            <div style=" background-color:cornflowerblue" class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex  justify-content-around" >
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1" >
                        <li>
                            <img class="logoimg" src="~/Images/SpaceRocket.png" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link  font-weight-bold text-dark " asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

`body` element has some initial margin at the begining and You need to reset it :)

```
 body {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Comment: To reset full browser-window use `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: @David i hope that helps :) If so, please mark the answer as approved :)

Comment: Yes thank you, there was also another class that was added from the program which was preventing the background color to change @AdamKniec

Answer (score 1):

your code is same with the picture i can't find any problems can you explain more?

Comment: i want the color to go all the way to the end

Comment: Your bgc is fine and the body color is full.
The problem should be with your parent.
like container padding or something like this...

Comment: Thank you that was one of the problems

Answer (score 1):

do you want to color the hole page with the same color , put style="background-color: cornflowerblue;" under the head . for your div only